# How to get the value from a batch apex class to a normal apex class

Tags: apex, visualforce, batch

So I've created a batch class, did a query, and stored the results into a map. Now I know that you can pass values from one batch to another with cascading batch calls and database.stateful, but is there a way to invoke the batch value through a normal Apex Class? Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: Here is the code for the apex batch class that populates the map. I need to somehow pass the map to another apex class and not using a cascading batch like I'm doing right now.

```
private String query;
public Map<Id, Id> agreementMap;
public Map<Id, Id> hierarchyMap = new Map<Id, Id>();
public List<AgreementHierarchy__c> hierarchyList = new List<AgreementHierarchy__c>();
public AgreementHierarchySupport support = new AgreementHierarchySupport();
public AgreementBatch(Map<Id, Id> agreement){
    agreementMap = agreement;
    query ='SELECT Id,leaf__c, parent__c FROM AgreementHierarchy__c';
}
public Database.querylocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
    //query the Agreement Hierarchy for the list to be passed on to the next batch
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
        }


    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> hierarchy){
            hierarchyList = hierarchy;
            hierarchyMap = support.populateHierarchy(hierarchyList);

    }
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {


        HierarchyBatch hier = new HierarchyBatch(agreementMap, hierarchyMap);
        Database.executeBatch(hier);
    }
```

Comment: Please include some code.

Comment: Of course, edited my post

Comment: Can't you store the results of your batch class in a record or custom setting?

Comment: I thought of doing so at first, but unfortunately we are not allowed to store the data in a record

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "another apex class"? You can instantiate any apex class from the `finish`, it doesn't have to be another batch. You can also call another static function in some utility class. What exactly are you trying to do?